# Como recarregar apenas tabela após ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou recarregando a página após inserir um dado no banco via ajax, existe  a possiblidade de atualizar ( reconstruir) só a tabela, ou a div em que ela esta?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#cadastrouser').hide();

$('#formcadastro').submit(function(event) {

    // process the form
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url         : 'cadastro.php', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : $("#formcadastro").serialize(), // our data object
        dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
        encode      : true
    })
        .done(function(data) {
            var resdata = data;
            if (resdata['sucesso']) {
                location.reload();
            }else{
                alert(resdata['mensagem']);
            }
        });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

});

Comment: edita e insere o que tem dentro de #formcadastro

Comment: Você pode manipular o DOM e adicionar na sua tabela, coloque um ID nela pra simplificar veja aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery

Comment: Não tem como reconstruir ?

Comment: basta você devolver o html por uma chamada em um arquivo separado ou um tratamento específico nesse seu php para retornar só o pedaço que preenche a tabela, e ai substituir o html do div. Tem muitas formas de fazer isso que você está querendo.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, se é que entendi sua pergunta, seria como atualizar/contruir dinamicamente uma tabela/div com AJAX, você pode fazer da seguinte forma.

Armazene em um arquivo o conteúdo que irá ser apresentado na sua tabela exemplo:

**tabela.php**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>conteúdo</td>
    </tr>
</tabela>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table").load("tabela.php");
});
```

Dessa forma ao iniciar o documento o jQuery irá carregar todo o conteúdo de **tabela.php** na sua tabela.